# CSS transition-duration, weird behaviour in IE 10

Tags: css, internet-explorer, transition

I'm working on a site that consists of a set of divs that are stacked on top of each other. To navigate you click on one of the layers and the other layers covering the clicked layer slide to the right. The layers are supposed to slide slowly (transition-duration is set to 0.7s).

This works great in all modern browsers except IE 10. There, the topmost layer slides faster (when coming from the right to the left) and when a layer is at the right edge of the screen and you hover over it it pops out immediately instead of transitioning smoothly. Can anyone tell me why this is? Is my CSS buggy or is this a problem with IE?

Here's the CSS that is applied to every layer:

```
position: absolute;
left: 160px; // this value differs slightly for every layer
-webkit-transition: left 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
-moz-transition: left 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
-o-transition: left 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
transition: left 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
```

Here's the CSS that is applied to a layer that slides to the right:

```
left: 100%;
```

Here's the CSS that is applied to layer that is slided to the right on mouseover (it's supposed to slide out a bit to the left):

```
left: 96%;
left: -webkit-calc(100% - 40px);
left: -moz-calc(100% - 40px);
left: -ms-calc(100% - 40px);
left: -o-calc(100% - 40px);
left: calc(100% - 40px);
```

Here's a link to the site: [Test site](http://mgieselmann.com/k/kd213/index.php)

**Update:** I noticed that when I take out the calc() property from the mouseover class, the animation works smoothly. Apparently IE cannot properly animate a property that has includes calc(). [This ticket](http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/762719/css3-calc-bug-inside-transition-or-transform) says it, too.

Now I am trying to target only Internet Explorer with a separate external stylesheet. But IE 10 [dropped support for conditional comments](http://www.sitepoint.com/microsoft-drop-ie10-conditional-comments/). Any Help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide the relative code so this question can benefit people further down the road. Don't just leave a link, it may not always be around.

Comment: Excellent idea, Josh. I added the important CSS parts. The whole setup is quite complex. Adding all the HTML, JS and CSS involved would be too much I am afraid. I hope this leads somewhere!

Comment: Thank you for adding more information, just real quick, I don't think `calc` needs the browser prefixes but I could be wrong.

Comment: Hi Josh, that's not the problem. I temporarily removed the prefixes to no avail. I added additional info, see my update above. The issue seems to be that IE 10 cannot make transitions when a property is set with calc().

Comment: As an alternative, you can add transitions with jQuery, since you are using it on your site.

Comment: Thanks Wellington. As I understand it, CSS transitions are more performant than jQuery animations. That is why I went with CSS. Am I correct?

Comment: Wellington, [this link](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/blog/jquery-vs-css3-transitions/) suggests that CSS transitions are the preferred way to animate. So now I am looking for a way to target IE 10 only. The goal would be to give IE 10 a different style rule that doesn't use calc().

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE 10 + 11: CSS transitions with calc() do not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142923/ie-10-11-css-transitions-with-calc-do-not-work)